# is it possible to pair the S3 bluetooth controller on ubuntu

Tags: gamepad

I want to get [this](http://www.gearbest.com/video-game/pp_197589.html) controller but I don't know if it works on Linux. Will it work on Linux?

Comment: I recommend checking this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sixaxis. You may need to write your own driver.

Comment: how do you write your own driver